# How is the order of ResourceDictionary keys determined?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I've got the following `ResourceDictionary` (shortened):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Fluent:RibbonContextualTabGroup Header="Dokument" x:Key="dokumentRibbonGroup" x:Name="dokumentRibbonGroup" />
  <Fluent:RibbonTabItem x:Key="dokumentRibbonTab" Header="Start" />
  <Fluent:RibbonTabItem x:Key="ueberpruefenRibbonTab" Header="Überprüfen" />
  <Fluent:RibbonTabItem x:Key="austauschRibbonTab" Header="Austausch" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I access the `Keys` property of the dictionary, the keys are in the following order:

```
dokumentRibbonTab
austauschRibbonTab
ueberpruefenRibbonTab
dokumentRibbonGroup
```

I can't make any sense of that order. It's not alphabetical, not revserse and in particular not the original order. Does anyone have a hint? Or even better, a suggestion on how to specify the order of items in a `ResourceDictionary`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may well be based on hash code somehow. (Not necessarily just "in ascending order of hash code" though.) In particular, the docs state:

> The ResourceDictionary class is not derived from DictionaryBase. Instead, the ResourceDictionary class implements IDictionary but relies on a Hashtable internally.

Given that it uses a hash table, it's likely that the order depends on the hash.

Typically dictionaries *aren't* ordered - or rather, the order is an implementation detail which shouldn't be relied on.

Given that I can't see any documentation specifying the ordering, I think you should *treat* it as unordered. If you want to present the keys in a particular order, you should do that yourself.

Comment: can we say that the order is as it is defined? but it will be applicable only for the StaticResource isn't it?

Comment: @Kishore: No, I don't believe there's any way of mandating it. It's unusual (IMO) to even *care* about the order.

Comment: for staticresource if we are referring any resource, it has to be defined before using that. what about in that case?

Comment: @Kishore: I don't think that will affect how they're ordered when *retrieving* them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that might explain it. So I will need to define an order differently, maybe using an attached property.